# I want to create a squares with 5 by 5 squares with a space but I am not sure how to?This is what I tried

Tags: python

```
y = topLeft.getY()
for i in range(5):
    x = topLeft.getX()
    for c in range(5):
        cellButton = CellButton(window,x,y,size,cellID=(i,c))
        self._buttons.append(cellButton)
        x= x + (size+padding)
    y = y + (size + padding)
```

#padding being space between each squares

I was expecting a 25 cell which is 5 by 5 with a space between them

Comment: The algorithm itself seems fine. It would help to know what CellButton is, maybe the arguments or the order is wrong? Reproducing this by printing squares with matplotlib creates the desired padding effect. Try to boil it down to a [mre] so that the error can be directly reproduced without guesswork.